# Why do the assignments to v, w behave differently?

Tags: java, shallow-copy

I would expect a shallow copy on v and output 701 801, but I see 700 801. I cannot see a good explanation. If w is a shallow copy, why not v? Does an Integer assigned an Integer "rebox"?

```
class Scalar {
    Integer w;
    public String toString() { return String.valueOf( w ); }
}

public class Demo {
    public Integer v;
    public Scalar scal;

    Demo shallowCopy() {
        Demo scopy = new Demo();
        scopy.v = this.v;  // <- Given this I would 701 from 
        scopy.scal = this.scal;
        return scopy;
    }

    public String toString() { return String.valueOf(v) + " " + scal.toString();  }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Demo d1 = new Demo();
        d1.v = 700;
        d1.scal = new Scalar();
        d1.scal.w = 800;
        Demo d2 = d1.shallowCopy();
        d2.v = 701;
        d2.scal.w = 801;
        System.out.println( d1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: The Java wrapper types are *immutable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d2.v = 701;` replaces the whole `Integer`.

Your shallow copy copies the reference to the `Integer` object held by `d1`, so `d2.v` has reference to the `Integer` object itself, not reference to `d1.v`.

On the other hand, `d2.scal` is not replaced. Therefore, `d1.scal` is equal to `d2.scal` because they are exactly the same object. If you change `scal.w`, it changes the value in that object, which will change for both `d1.scal` and `d2.scal`. Meanwhile, overwriting `d2.v` changes the reference, but does not change the object pointed to by `d2.v` itself, hence not `d1.v`.